# Why is my mint plant stem turning black?

Tags: mint

I just got a mint plant but half of the stem are black, and some of the leaves are black and shrivelled. Any idea on how to fix this problem, and how to take care of the mint plant?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the stem has died.  Needs a picture though.

Comment: Something like [this](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19326/my-mint-is-dying-out)?